# AngularJS: Inject dependencies while $provide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-services

I am a newbie to AngularJS. I am trying to develop a single page application in salesforce CRM plarform. I wanted to load the dependencies on demand i.e., only when the user click a particular link. I have also achieved this by using https://github.com/matys84pl/angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers

The above link has examples for directives alone. I have added services and filter in the same route configuration file.

```
function registerServices(service) {    
  if(service) {
    if (!$provide){ throw new Error("Error: $setProvide is not set!"); }
    $provide.value(service[0], service[1]);
  } else {
    $provide.value = null; 
  }
}
```

I'm registering a service like the above and it can be used as,

```
service = ['serviceName', function(){
   return {
     a: 1, b:2
   }
}]
```

Everything is working great, But my doubt is, how to inject the dependencies such $q, $rootScope, etc in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about lazy loading but, if lazy loading work then the standard method of injection may work

```
service = ['serviceName', '$rootScope','$q', function($rootScope, $q){
   return {
     a: 1, b:2
   }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this problem, I am not sure whether the way is proper.

**Controller**

```
var controller = function($scope, customService){
   $scope.name = "hello world";
   customService($q, $rootScope).then(function(data){ 
      console.log(data);
      /*Received data can be manipulated*/ 
   });
}
```

**Service**

```
'use strict';
define(function () {
    return ['customService', function($q, $rootScope){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        /*Your code*/
        return deferred.promise;
    }];
})
```